# The namespace bla already contains a definition for  (my partial) class

Tags: c#, class, partial

I've created a program with some very big .cs files. So i tried  to split one of them up by using partial classes. So i created a second file with same class name inside and same namespace.
I cut some functions from one file and pasted it in the second one. But when i want to run the program it says that the class already exists. But its a partial class it has to have the same name :S

At the first file (ChartWidget.cs) it starts with:

```
namespace UGS.Sidebar.ChartWidget
{
    public partial class ChartWidget : UserControl
    {
        #region declarations
        private int id = -1;
```

.....

At the second file (Debugging.cs) it starts with:

```
namespace UGS.Sidebar.ChartWidget
{
    public partial class ChartWidget : UserControl
    {

        #region debugvars
        Random _r = new Random();
        #endregion
        .....
```

those files are from an Usercontrol (as you can see) but i dont think that this is the problem?

Hope you guys can tell me why it doesnt work :(
And sorry for my bad english i really suck ... :)

Comment: That should work...what happens when you put them in the same file?

Comment: Can you _copy_ the error message and paste it into your question?

Comment: Are the definitions in the same assembly?

Comment: I found the mistake! The namespace was wrong. i had to change it to UGS.Sidebar... i dont really get the thing with namespaces, i should look it up on msdn :D.
Thanks anyway :)))

Comment: I have to vote this question down since you didn't do the proper amount of research before asking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to inherit from UserControl in second class

Comment: To clarify @Zafar's post, he's saying: Don't do `ChartWidget : UserControl` twice.

Comment: haha yes i understood what Zaraf said :D
But its still not working and i dont understand why :(
But thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Take a loot at it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: This doesn't address the OPs issue.

Comment: yeah i was looking at this page for hours :D but it wasn't helping me!
But i found the mistake! The namespace was wrong. i had to change it to UGS.Sidebar... i dont really get the thing with namespaces, i should look it up on msdn :D

thanks anyway, haven't noticed the thing with the :UserControl!

Comment: There is no need to specify the base class twice, but is not forbidden

Answer (score 17):

Check you haven't appended the class name on to the end of a namespace. e.g. if you put your new class into a folder of the same name, it will automatically get suffixed on the namespace name

Comment: This was it for me. Thanks for that. I would have been searching for ever!

Comment: Similar to this, my problem was that creating class file inside subfolder results in automatic namespace generated reflecting the folder structure. Of course it won't treat the two as one class. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Check if somewhere else the class is defined without the partial. `Right click on the class name + Find All Reference` could help.

Comment: This requires the project being successfully built, which cannot be accomplished due to this error.